# Domain and email validation

Tags: python, validation

I need a domain validator and email validator, ie validate if both exist. The company I'm servicing has a website that validates this for them, ensuring they won't send email to a nonexistent mailbox. It would be an email marketing action anyway. They have something basic about excel, but they want a service to be running directly getting a list of information and or transactional so that it checks by lot, speeding up the process. It is a work very similar to what makes this [site](https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io).

I would like to develop something similar in python rather. I would like to know if such a work is feasible and if so, if anyone could give me some reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For validating emails, this depends on how specifically you want to validate them. If you just want to check that the email follows the basic `x@y.tld` format, then you can use a regular expression - if you want to check the domain at the same time to make sure that the mailbox can exist, then using a module is probably your best bet.

[pyIsEmail](https://github.com/michaelherold/pyIsEmail) is a good choice - it also has the facility to check if the domain the email address is from is real, and if it also has a valid MX record attached.

```
from pyisemail import is_email

address = "test@example.com"
bool_result = isemail(address)
bool_result_with_dns = is_email(address, check_dns=True)
```

[Flanker](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker) can also be used for this purpose - as well as checking DNS, MX records and ESP grammar for each email, it can take a list of email records and return a tuple containing lists of the valid and invalid emails.

```
>>> from flanker.addresslib import address
>>>
>>> address.validate_list(['foo@mailgun.com, bar@mailgun.com, @mailgun.com'], as_tuple=True)
([foo@mailgun.com, bar@mailgun.com], ['@mailgun.com'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the email is exist or not, it is better to use an online email validation service to do so, since those service are able you to reach the corresponding mail server and verify is the email address exist or not. At here I will recommend you one email validation service call [MailboxValidator](https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/) . It has free plan to start, and is easy to use with. They has developed their own Python package, so you can start off with that. Example code:

```
import MailboxValidator

mbv = MailboxValidator.SingleValidation('PASTE_API_KEY_HERE')
results = mbv.ValidateEmail('example@example.com')

if results is None:
    print("Error connecting to API.\n")
elif results['error_code'] == '':
    print('email_address = ' + results['email_address'] + "\n")
    print('domain = ' + results['domain'] + "\n")
    print('is_free = ' + results['is_free'] + "\n")
    print('is_syntax = ' + results['is_syntax'] + "\n")
    print('is_domain = ' + results['is_domain'] + "\n")
    print('is_smtp = ' + results['is_smtp'] + "\n")
    print('is_verified = ' + results['is_verified'] + "\n")
    print('is_server_down = ' + results['is_server_down'] + "\n")
    print('is_greylisted = ' + results['is_greylisted'] + "\n")
    print('is_disposable = ' + results['is_disposable'] + "\n")
    print('is_suppressed = ' + results['is_suppressed'] + "\n")
    print('is_role = ' + results['is_role'] + "\n")
    print('is_high_risk = ' + results['is_high_risk'] + "\n")
    print('is_catchall = ' + results['is_catchall'] + "\n")
    print('mailboxvalidator_score = ' + str(results['mailboxvalidator_score']) + "\n")
    print('time_taken = ' + str(results['time_taken']) + "\n")
    print('status = ' + results['status'] + "\n")
    print('credits_available = ' + str(results['credits_available']) + "\n")
else:
    print('error_code = ' + results['error_code'] + "\n")
    print('error_message = ' + results['error_message'] + "\n")
```

You can find more information at [here](https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/python).